# Check if values exist in Java Streams and if so then map them to integers

Tags: java

I have a Java List and I am trying to check if certain values exist in this list map them to 1 else to 0.

```
List<String> status1 = Arrays.asList("UPS","USPS","FEDEX","DHL","AMAZON");
status1
    .stream()
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .map((s -> s.equals("ups") ? 1 : 0) || (s -> s.equals("fedex") ? 1 : 0))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: you may want to use groupby instead of map for that, take a look at this https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector

Comment: Your lambda in the map should be `s -> (s.equals("ups") || s.equals("fedex")) ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the lambda in `map`:

```
Arrays.asList("UPS","USPS","FEDEX","DHL","AMAZON")
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(s -> 
            "ups".equalsIgnoreCase(s) || "fedex".equalsIgnoreCase(s) ? 1 :0)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> status1 = Arrays.asList("USPS","DHL","AMAZON");
            int result=    status1.stream().anyMatch(s-> s.equals("UPS")||s.equals("FEDEX"))?1:0;
```

Comment: This won't compile. anyMatch returns a boolean, and you're missing a parentheses.

Comment: You need a parentheses before the semicolon

Comment: Compiles in my eclipse IDE